# Will moveit accept a list of goals?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using a custom node to accept a list of waypoints and send them one at a time to move_base when the current waypoint is successfully reached.  So I can send it a path that the robot will travel.

**Does moveit already have this functionality?**

I saw the MotionGroup Action message that has the MotionPlanRequest member which in turn has the Constraints[] member. So I know it can accept a list of constraints but nothing I can find specifies the behaviour of that list.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I want to be able to send an ordered list of waypoints in some frame to moveit.  It will compute the necessary trajectory for the first waypoint.  Once it reaches that waypoint moveit will compute the trajectory for the next and so on.

Example (I am assuming a local frame and units in meters):

(frame: "base_link", [(1,1), (3, -3), (0, 0)])

The robot will travel to 1 meter forward and 1 meter right, then continue on to 3 meters forward and 3 meters left (from the original location).  I am not concerned about frames right now just the iteration through a list of waypoints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55645/will-moveit-accept-a-list-of-goals?/) by [virgil93](https://answers.ros.org/users/2735/virgil93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean the ability to follow a trajectory? That would be performed by your own robot's controllers that listen to a "control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction" actionlib message. This action is sent from MoveIt.

Or are you looking at doing time parameterization of a list of waypoints, to generate velocities, accelerations and wait times for wach waitpoint? This can be accomplished by MoveIt.

I don't understand how that relates to the second half of your question about constraints though, I'm afraid.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-02-19**:
Got it. I haven't seen this functionality but your could easily just feed them one at a time to MoveIt as it completes each waypoint. You are desiring to have it plan all of it at once I presume?

**Comment by [virgil93](https://answers.ros.org/users/2735/virgil93/) on 2013-02-20**:
No, it doesn't have to plan all the waypoints at once.  Just the current one in the list.  Thanks for your answer though.

**Comment by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on 2017-03-08**:
HI all
I have knew how the time,velocities, accelerations is generated.They are look like a average value for smooth curve.

but I get a problem that I do't how to use time,velocities,accelerations to control a motor,I can't use them all.